# Why background-color: hsl() in qt css work in different way than in web css

Tags: qt

For example, `background-color: hsl(120, 100%, 100%)` in browser is white, but in Qt is light green. It seems, that `hsl()` function in Qt CSS behaves like HSV. Or where I am wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `hsl()` and `hsv()` produce the same color in Qt. This is either a bug or a result of HSL coloring not being supported. If you need to [convert from HSL to HSV](https://codeitdown.com/hsl-hsb-hsv-color/) on the fly you can do the following:

```
int H_hsv = H_hsl;  // This is the easy one of course
double V_hsv = (2 * L_hsl + S_hsl * (1 - abs(2 * L_hsl - 1))) / 2;
double S_hsv = (2 * (V_hsv - L_hsl)) / V_hsv;
```

If you have `H_hsl` an `int` in the range `[0-360]` and `double`s  `S_hsl` and `L_hsl` as decimal percentages in the range `[0.0,1.0]`. The resulting values can then be converted to `QString`s using `Qstring::number()` or into `std::string`s using `std::to_string()` and concatenated to construct the `stylesheet` argument, i.e.

```
setStyleSheet("background-color: hsv("+QString::number(H_hsv)+", "
  +QString::number(S_hsv * 100)+"%, "+QString::number(V_hsv * 100)+"%);");
```

---

## Complete example

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qmainwindow.h>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow* main = new QMainWindow;
    QWidget* central = new QWidget();

    double S_hsl = 1;
    double L_hsl = 1;
    int H_hsl = 120;

    int H_hsv = H_hsl;  // This is the easy one of course
    double V_hsv = (2 * L_hsl + S_hsl * (1 - abs(2 * L_hsl - 1))) / 2;
    double S_hsv = (2 * (V_hsv - L_hsl)) / V_hsv;

    central->setStyleSheet("background-color: hsv(" + QString::number(H_hsv) + ", "
        + QString::number(S_hsv * 100) + "%, " + QString::number(V_hsv*100) + "%);");

    main->setCentralWidget(central);
    main->resize(600, 400);
    main->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Good answer but you might need to do `abs(V_hsv - L_hsl)` as well as `abs(2 * L_hsl - 1)` since this will fail if `V_hsv < L_hsl`.

Comment: @Ghost the lightness in HSL can never be greater than the value in HSV because of how the RGB color space is mapped in HSV - [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)